# Why is getDataRange.getValues() not pulling all the required values?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, scripting

I have a spreadsheet, and I would like to use google scripts (JS based) to put all of that data into an array and then search through that array for information. The code I have below does not work, and returns nothing in the logger:

```js
function openNCR() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var NCRData = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var data = NCRData.getDataRange.getValues();
  var search = 'Open NCR'
  var target_rows = []

  data.forEach(function(element, index) {
    if (element == search) {
      target_rows.push(index)
    }
  })

  Logger.log(target_rows);
}
```

Yet when I make the change below in terms of how to pull the information, the code works great! What is the key difference here in the above and below? Doesn't getDataRange.getValues pull all the values within that sheet? If that is the case, then why do I need to define a specific column to search through as per below (column 3 is the column that contains the information "Open NCR" or "Closed NCR")?

```js
function openNCR() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var NCRData = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var data = NCRData.getRange(1, 3, NCRData.getLastRow()).getValues()
  var search = 'Open NCR'
  var target_rows = []

  data.forEach(function(element, index) {
    if (element == search) {
      target_rows.push(index)
    }
  })

  Logger.log(target_rows);
}
```

Comment: Look at the docs, the getValues function needs a range to work with: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Answer (score 0):

.getDataRange() is a method from the class 'Sheet' and thus requires brackets.

```
 var data = NCRData.getDataRange().getValues();
```